# Настройка распознавания лиц в OpenCV

Tags: java, c++, opencv, распознавание-образов, javacv

У меня есть набор изображений для обучения: для двух персон по 10 изображений и 80 изображений различных персон для проверки достоверности распознавания. Имеется 3 контрольных изображения, по 1 с каждой персоной и одна общая с десяткой персон (в которую входят первые две и несколько из 80). На всех изображениях персоны расположены фронтально. Хотелось бы в результате распознавания на всех 3 контрольных изображениях опознать две персоны, для которых производилось обучение с помощью 10 изображений.
Проблема заключается в том, что все 3 алгоритма (LBPH, Fisherfaces, Eigenfaces) не справились с этой задачой (на одном или двух изображениях помечают персону другой, причем для которой было всего 1 обучающее изображение), очевидно, у меня где-то ошибка в последовательности обучения или распознавания, или я чего-то не учел.

Добавление изображения для обучения:

1. считать изображения для обучения в градациях серого
2. определить позицию лица и сделать новое изображение на основе этой позиции
3. для алгоритов кроме LBPH привести изображения к одному размеру (я так и не смог определить, какой лучше всего размер использовать, наугад тыкал разные)
4. [Histogram Equalization](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d1b/tutorial_histogram_equalization.html)
5. добавить в вектор который потом пойдет в обучение

Добавление изображения для распознавания:

1. Определить все лица на изображении в градации серого и для каждого выполнить
2. сделать новое изображение на основе позиции
3. для алгоритов кроме LBPH привести изображения к одному размеру
4. Histogram Equalization
5. отправить на распознавание

Буду рад принять любые советы и ответить на Ваши вопросы, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Процесс распознавания лица можно разбить на 3 стадии:

1. выделение области с лицом
2. нормализация изображения
3. сравнение и анализ

OpenCV предоставляет утилиты для 1 и 3 стадии, а вот 2 стадию (самую сложную) возлагает ответственность на пользователя. 
Алгоритмы LBPH, Fisherfaces, Eigenfaces достигают 90% точности распознавания на специально подготовленных изображениях (нормализованных). Если взять подборку AT&T, то можно заметить, что у них все изображения: имеют одинаковый размер (ширина и высота), все приведены к градации серого с нормализацией, однотонный фон, лица отцентрированы и произведено выравнивание на основе опорных точек и произведены другие методы нормализации. [Пример выполнения процесса нормализации](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78). [Разбор и анализ алгоритмов распознавания, используемых в OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/face/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html). [AT&T Facedatabase](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/facedatabase.html).

Таким образом, проблема низкой точности распознавания в моем случае заключалась в том, что изображения имели низкий уровень нормализации. Для повышения уровня точности нужно либо добавлять различные алгоритмы для нормализации изображений, либо использовать для распознавания более современные алгоритмы, основанные на нейронных сетях и машинном обучении

После нормализации [на основе алгоритма из статьи](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/05/22/face-alignment-with-opencv-and-python/) существенно увеличилась точность определения (я добавил поворот и масштабирование изображения на основе положения глаз).

Comment: Рекомендую использовать DLIB вместо OpenCV и JavaCV - библиотека имеет утилиту нормализацию изображений и алгоритмы распознавания на основе нейронных сетей. Из минусов стоит отметить, что придется писать на с++

Answer (score 5):

В рамках учебного процесса выполнял ваши задачи(как раз эти три алгоритма), вот [github](https://github.com/StriBog45/Face-Recognition-2.4.9-EMGU-)

Если вкратце, брал изображение с камеры и определял, кто этот человек из локальной базы данных(набор изображений). Там есть форма, в которой можете покрутить параметры по всем трем алгоритмам

Но github не позволил загрузить библиотеки emgu с проектом, т.к. они слишком много весят, вам придется добавить их вручную

Если нужно будет, я могу их загрузить отдельно через другой ресурс